# how to print contents of a jpanel as text?

Tags: java, printing

I'm using netbeans and I have the code to print a jpanel and it works fine. However, its output is that it prints the jpanel as an image. This is not ideal for me as it also prints a faded gray color in the background which is the size of the jpanel. I only want to print the text in the jpanel which consists of many jlabels. Is there a way to print the contents of a jpanel as text and not an image?

This is the code that I used to print the contents of my jpanel

```
    PrinterJob job = PrinterJob.getPrinterJob();
     job.setJobName("jPanel13");

     job.setPrintable (new Printable() {    
        public int print(Graphics pg, PageFormat pf, int pageNum){
            if (pageNum > 0){
            return Printable.NO_SUCH_PAGE;
            }

            Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) pg;
            g2.translate(pf.getImageableX(), pf.getImageableY());
            jPanel13.paint(g2);
            return Printable.PAGE_EXISTS;
        }
     });
     boolean ok = job.printDialog();
     if (ok) {
         try {
              job.print();
         } catch (PrinterException ex) {

         }
```

This is a printscreen of the jpanel that I need to print. In my program, the text values of the jlabels can be changed by the user. The jlabels texts will then be printed to fill in the blank lines a form. The form will already have writing on it; it is only the blank lines that I will fill-up when printing. That is why it is important that the jlabels are positioned in that way.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kPKWe.jpg

[image]

Comment: Can you show us an image of this JPanel to give us an idea of just what you're trying to do?

Comment: thank you for replying, i just edited my post

Comment: I have edited your original question and have uploaded your image so that it will show without folks having to go to another site. Myself, if I had to solve this problem, I'd search for a form-creation library because I'm sure that one has been created to solve just this sort of problem so that I wouldn't have to try to create a kludge solution using a GUI in a way that it wasn't built to be used.

Comment: yes thank you, it would not let me post the image because i am a new user. ok i will search for one, thank you. do you happen to know any libraries that you suggest?

Comment: No, not off hand. I'd have to do what you must do: check Google and then ask around.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the `JPanel` background is the only problem, you can call `print()` on it instead of `paint()`, and override `printComponent()` to do nothing (the default just calls `paintComponent()`).

Alternately, just set the background color to white while printing.